# Powering Ardunio Nano with external 5V Schematic

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, power-supply, atmega, hardware

This is the continuation of my ([previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/583411/powering-arduino-nano-with-5v?noredirect=1#comment1527749_583411)).  In that, it is suggested that powering a Nano with an external 5V is not a good method.  My team told me to put an option in any way.  I found this material ([Power Arduino Nano with an external power supply](https://wiki.fryktoria.com/doku.php?id=arduino:external-power-supply)) on the internet.

A new requirement came such that we need to power using an external 5V supply and use USB communication at the same time.

This says that if you are connecting an external 5V to the 5V pin of Arduino Nano you can connect a Schottky diode at the output of the external 5V regulator.

If we power from an external 5V regulator with the help of a Schottky diode how does the Arduino determine which source to take?

Below is my schematic.' ARD_5V_IN' is the external 5V supply to Arduino.

[image]

Comment: A great explanation was already given to you in previous question. Now it's unclear if do you really need to power with +5V external **AND** by the USB **at the same time**?

Comment: The previous explanation was very clear and best. But the new requirement is I need to power with USB and external 5V regulator at the same time.

Comment: You haven't made your use-case completely clear. One common case is that the external supply will always be connected to the Arduino so that it will always have power and can run autonomously. On occasion, the USB cable will be plugged in to communicate with the Arduino or update firmware. If that is your case then simply break the connection between Vusb and the PCB. There will never be any conflict. Either cut a convenient trace or remove D1 or the filter inductor at the input of Vusb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 5V power comes from an LDO like LM317 then you can wired OR the outputs and whichever is slightly higher takes the load continuously.

Comment: An LM317 is not an LDO, which stands for "Low Drop Out"

Comment: LM317 was the original adjustable LDO for BJT technology and discrete versions back the day were much higher dropout,so they adopted this name. it is the same as a 7805 except may be used as LDO for adjustable output or NON-LDO. Your choice.  You can even regulate 1002.5V to 1000V with 997.5V reference. Do you really think I didn't know what LDO meant (?) ;)

Comment: Do you trust Rohm? They call it an LDO, others in marketing might say "Positive Regulator" to avoid jokes,... https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/baxxbc0-e-1874116.pdf

Comment: As linear regulators go, the LM317 has a relatively high drop-out. Marketing doesn't change that fact.

Comment: 3V @ 1.5A max vs 2V nom @ 1A and the fact they used the same internal output Darlington stage with a fixed series Re (0.25) means this is a pointless semantic discussion about historical designs that are no longer both considered "Low Differential Dropout" compared the FET versions now. But for the purposes of this discussion LDO means Wired Or any linear Darlington output or LDO will work in parallel with another voltage source (within reasonable tolerances ). Including Rohm's equivalent not so low nowadays Adjustable LDO.

Answer (score 1):

There's yet another scenario and that's when the LDO is not powered but you connect 5V from the USB. The USB supplied voltage will then enter the LDO from behind and when Vin is much lower than Vout, almost every LDO out there will fry.

One quick & dirty hack to protect against this is to put a schottky across the LDO with the cathode against Vin, so that when you get supply backwards you get Vin ~4.8V and Vout 5.0V and that's usually enough for the LDO to survive.

A more serious solution is to put the USB supply on the Vin side of the voltage regulator. But then you can't have a simple LDO there. A simple switched boost regulator might do the trick. If you pick one carefully then you get the option to supply the board from a battery for free.